store type as variable and use in list<T> c#?
I am trying to store a type as a variable so that I can make a List object with a few different possible types without hard coding them all.
My code basically looks like this:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    int a = 10;
    string b = "hello";
    Type intType = a.GetType();
    Type stringType = b.GetType();
    List<intType> intList = new List<intType>();
    List<stringType> stringList = new List<stringType>();
  }
}

When I run this, however, I get the following error:
main.cs(8,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name typeContainer' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`
Is there a better way to do this?  Am I doing something stupid and don't realize it?
Thank you.

have you looked into a generic class?

If the type is not static in the code, you can't use it directly as generic. You need to create a new Type for that. You should read this How to: Examine and instantiate generic types with reflection. If you haven't done much with reflection yet, this is some tough material. The "magic" is in the MakeGenericType(...) method which creates a new type with the types you pass as parameter.
